# Why am I getting next error: Trying to get property of non-object? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

```
class Article extends Model
{       
    protected $fillable = ['category_id','author_id','title','img','description','text'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }    
    public function article_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory');
    }
}

class ArticleCategory extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'article_categories';    
    protected $fillable = ['name','hide'];    
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
}

User model
    public function article()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
        }
```

Why am I getting error when trying to get author name and article category name?

Trying to get it in view this way:
$article->user->name
$article->article_category->name

Can't understand the reason :c

Comment: Because what you have isn't an object.

Comment: What do you get if you try $article->user()->name

Comment: @ChrisTownsend Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name

Comment: Could you dd($artifle->user()); and put the output in your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory');
```

To

`return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');`

and

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory', 'foreign_key);
```

Both will receive the properly foreign key that you provide in yours tables on migrations. Perhaps your foreign keys doesn't recognized.